# White lines in Plot3D and exclusions in documentation

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, documentation

I am aware that this issue has come up before in a number of posts. However, my question is a little different and as far as I can see not answered previously.

If I run the following code taken directly from the Mathematica documentation

```
Plot3D[CosineWindow[x] CosineWindow[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get

[image]

Note the white lines.

This is not consistent with the image shown in the documentation.

[image]

If I re-run the code in the documentation notebook I get the plot with the white lines.

I am fully aware that using `Exclusions -> None` removes the white lines. As in

```
Plot3D[CosineWindow[x] CosineWindow[y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

My questions

1. Why is the image shown in the documentation inconsistent with the actual output of the code shown in the documentation. I would have expected the image in the documentation to match the actual output of the code.
2. For this specific example using `CosineWindow` are the white lines meant to be there? I can semi understand the lines directly around the perimeter of the "bump", presumably due to a discontinuity(?). But I am not clear why the lines span the whole plot, where the function should be zero.

I am running "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Comment: ExclusionsStyle -> Yellow

Comment: The white lines are there for me too on 12.1 for Linux. The discrepancy with the documentation can happen because they generated that on a system / version of Mathematica where these white lines did not appear.

Comment: So, has some internal behaviour of Mathematica changed? Are the lines meant to be there? Particularly there spanning the whole plot?

Comment: `Options[Plot3D, Exclusions]` evaluates to `{Exclusions->Automatic}`. Presumably, the code that decides what is `Automatic` for a given case changed and now concludes that it should mean `True` for this specific case. As you pointed out, you can override its decision.

Comment: Are the white lines spanning the whole plot mathematically correct? Why not just around the "bump"?

Comment: Discrepancies in the docs, such as this one, are worth reporting to Support.